# Generating Excel from program data by the same schema

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I need to create excel file from same data (List). And I want to identify universal schema for the file creation which allow me not to set cell values manually.

I know that the same functionality have DevExpress and Crystal Reports, but they are not for free, unfortunately (are there any free equivalents for .NET Core?)

Thank you.

Comment: This sounds like two questions. One is how to create the file. That's the easy part. The other is to identify a schema. That part is less clear. Do you want to lock the cells to prevent editing, or just ensure that there are validation rules so that each cell has the correct type of data?

Comment: @Scott Hannen, yes, simple excel table creation isn't so hard - I can use EPPlus. But I want to use the same schema for automata excel creation from the my app data. The simplest example - parsing json container to the excel table, for example. Harder - xml/json schema usage for automata class fields binding and parsing List<Somedata> to excel file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've found a great (as for me and my tasks) package - https://github.com/mganss/ExcelMapper. I can't find similar packages with the same functionality. Hope, this project will have a long life!